# Heroku Slow Loading Throughout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

My Heroku Rails is always loading extremely slowly and not only at first start.

It doesnt load this slowly in production mode.

I have New-Relic Installed, I have two Dynos running and I have PostgreSQL Crane Plan. But when I start my app it will normally take about 30 seconds to load and 60% of the time it'll go straight to `Application Error`, if I check my logs I get `Memory Quota Exceeded`. Even if I go to a static page with no Ruby in its source, it'll still load slowly. Sometimes I manage to connect to my app and it will normally take around 10 seconds to load when navigating from page to page. 
I've been looking online for ages and all the most common answer I find is to just add an extra dyno, but that doesnt help.

Im also running on Unicorn

These are the logs from a movies#show page which loaded at first and then crashed

```
Started GET "/movies/61708" for 81.34.154.155 at 2013-08-29 23:08:23 +0000
2013-08-29T23:08:30.093034+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path=/?page=7 host=www.websitename.com fwd="81.34.154.155" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-08-29T23:08:31Z app[postgres.8916]: [BLUE] duration: 6945.946 ms  statement: SELECT "movies".* FROM "movies" 
2013-08-29T23:08:41+00:00 app[heroku-postgres]: source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLUE measure.current_transaction=2844 measure.db_size=60732536bytes measure.tables=23 measure.active-connections=10 measure.waiting-connections=0 measure.index-cache-hit-rate=1 measure.table-cache-hit-rate=1
2013-08-29T23:08:45.401673+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path=/movies/63724 host=www.websitename.com fwd="81.34.154.155" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-08-29T23:08:45.445116+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path=/movies/63704 host=www.websitename.com fwd="81.34.154.155" dyno=web.2 connect=3ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-08-29T23:08:52.684401+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Process running mem=512M(100.0%)
2013-08-29T23:08:52.684613+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2013-08-29T23:08:53.647059+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2013-08-29T23:08:53.384868 #2] ERROR -- : worker=0 PID:5 timeout (61s > 60s), killing
2013-08-29T23:08:54.375154+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2013-08-29T23:08:54.374971 #2] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 5 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=0
```

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Check your logs again; paste relevant bits here. Look for patterns in your logs suggesting loops/hanging where there shouldn't be. Maybe you're loading far too much from the database at once. You're consuming lots of memory. The solution is to determine the source of the consumption and fix it. I'm not being snarky - we just can't help you based solely on the description you've provided.

Comment: I've added the logs. But the thing is, I havent even launched yet so it's just me requesting info from the database. My database can't even handle one user?

Comment: How many movies do you have? 7 seconds for a simple select is pretty absurd. You shouldn't really have any reason to dump an entire table into memory as Rails models - it's very likely the source of the trouble you're having.

Comment: What do you mean? There are currently 60k rows in the movies table, this shouldn't be a problem? I am paying for PostgreSQL crane which should give me 10 million rows

Comment: Actually, PostgreSQL Crane should give me unlimited rows with 410 MB of Random Access Memory

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned in the comments you have `60,000` rows in your `movies` table. From your logs it appears you're doing something like the following:

```
Movie.all
```

This will generate an SQL query like what we see in your logs.

```
SELECT "movies".* FROM "movies"
```

The memory/storage capacity of Postgres doesn't matter with respect to your issue. Your database could be on a dedicated server with 96G RAM. You'll still end up with the same problem on Heroku's end.

When you do something like `Movie.all`, you're creating in-memory ruby class instances of `Movie` for all `60,000` records. This takes time and space.

You're probably also rendering too many *(dare I say **all**?!)* of these records to a single webpage at once. This is simply *way* too much data to render during a single request, whether you're on Heroku or not.

Heroku has a hard 30s time limit for it's request's running time. You're hitting this limit. Try a **much** smaller subset of data, even just as a test, and see if it solves your issues. I'm betting it will.

```
Movie.limit(10)
```

Comment: Maybe you do, but you're still calling `Movie.all` **somewhere**, causing all 60k records to load into memory. Your logs don't lie.

Comment: My controller 

`@explore_movies = Movie.limit(20).where('release_date is not null').all(:order => "release_date desc")`

Comment: So how do I get rid of that `all`, whilst still have .where and :order.
Im still limiting to 20

Comment: `Movie.where('release_date is not null').order("release_date desc").limit(20)`

Comment: I push it to Heroku and I still get `Process running mem=635M(124.1%)
Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
`

Comment: Is your log still showing the `select * from movies` query without the limit? It may be elsewhere in your code.